# select class without hidden word via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a page where class `"check-cls agent-cls corporate-cls log-out-cls hidden"` is present. When I run below jQuery command it is returning me the result:

Jquery:

```
$(".check-cls.agent-cls.corporate-cls.log-out-cls");
```

> Result : 0: li.check-cls.agent-cls.corporate-cls.log-out-cls.hidden

Why it is taking hidden class also? I want to perform action on element having class `.check-cls.agent-cls.corporate-cls.log-out-cls` but action is getting applied on `li.check-cls.agent-cls.corporate-cls.log-out-cls.hidden` also.

Comment: Please show your html and js code.

Comment: Because `.a.b.c` is also `.a.b`

Comment: Seeing the html and js in this case would make no difference - why is that the go-to comment when it's not included, even where it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 2):

As you are using Multiple Class Selector, it will target element having both classes the element with class `"check-cls agent-cls corporate-cls log-out-cls hidden"` fulfills the requirement.

Using [`:not()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) you can exclude element with `.hidden` class

```
$(".check-cls.agent-cls.corporate-cls.log-out-cls:not(.hidden)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **:visible**

```
$(".check-cls.agent-cls.corporate-cls.log-out-cls:visible");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the jquery selector is matching the classes with all the elements. Now since the element with hidden class also has these classes it is being selected.

To select the element with all the class names defined by you and not having the hidden class do,

```
$(".check-cls.agent-cls.corporate-cls.log-out-cls").not('.hidden');
```

or

```
$(".check-cls.agent-cls.corporate-cls.log-out-cls:not(.hidden)")
```